# Is there a plan to create a new category for Natty questions

Tags: feature-request, answer-format

Hope we will have many many question in the coming days regarding the new release Natty. Is there a plan to create a new category for Natty questions? shall we continue as it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[11.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/11.04) and triaging duplicates outta do the trick.

Comment: You are right i understand this after readying tagging index